# OPENGL (glfw) - can't find -lGLFW

Tags: opengl, code-blocks

I tried to setup GLFW for Ubuntu (Code::Blocks) but I can't find where is the problem.
So I installed the `glfw` package via:

```
sudo apt-get install libglfw3-dev
```

Then, I added GLFW to the build properties of my Code::Blocks project.

In order to test it, I wrote this little code and tried it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    if (!glfwInit())
{
    // Handle initialization failure
}
    return 0;
}
```

I still have this:

```
||=== Build: Debug in test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
ld||cannot find -lGLFW|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike other OpenGL libraries `libGL.so`, `libGLU.so`, `libGLEW.so` and so on, the library file for GLFW is all lower case:

```
$ pkg-config --libs gl glfw3
-lGL -lglfw
```

Therefore you need to change `-lGLFW` to `-lglfw` in your build script.